# Progress dialog problem

Tags: android

Actually i have a problen while using progress dialog.The problem is not with the progress dialog.What i find difficult is.

I call a function onPause() of an activty say

```
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   setData();
}
```

Now onBackpressed() method i display an progressdialog, and the code i have use is

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{           
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    Thread reminderThread = new Thread() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3 * 1000);
                ReminderForm.this.finish();
                progressDialog.dismiss();                           
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };reminderThread.start();
 }
```

Now my problem is that when i enter Data and call setData() on the onPause() method it takes times to exit from at that activity.So during that time i display the progress bar when the user click back button.so these work fine but when the user enter no data then i want the progress bar to show but with less time as shown when the user enter data and call the setData() method of onPause() method.But in my case whether the user enter data or not the progressBar will take 3 sec.So is there any way where i can get the time of first thread and put that time in my second thread.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you want to do this at all.  ProgressDialogs are only supposed to be shown when there's work going on that the user has to wait on before continuing.  You're just sleeping for three seconds from showing the dialog to dismissing it.  In other words, the work can be done at 1/2 a second but the user is still waiting for 2 1/2 seconds.

Comment: What are trying to do? the functionality.. not the problem u having now.

Comment: Actually on pause method when i call that function by input data then it take time to exit from that activity.But when i input nothing than it quickly exit.So i want to display a progress dialog when it takes time to exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handler.postDelayed method would be your friend in this case.  Instead of spawning a new thread and executing code to perform a delay, Handler.postDelayed will allow you to set the amount of time to wait and pass in a Runnable to be executed on the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29

**EDIT**

Actually, I take that back.  After re-reading, it seems what you want to do is save state when the user presses the back button, show a dialog during this time, and then dismiss the dialog and finish the activity when done.  This is what you need:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new SaveStateTask().execute();
}

protected void saveMyActivityState() {
    // Do your stuff for however long it takes...
    // This is executing on a background thread...
}

class SaveStateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        NameOfYourActivity.this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        saveMyActivityState();

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i implement in my code.Can you please show me with an example that relate my code

Comment: Updated my response.  I think this is more along the lines of what you're looking for.  Let me know if it's not.

Comment: yeh its working.but on SaveMyactivityState() when i call onPause() function..the progress dialog rotate for an sec and then stop for another sec of time rotating when the activity is going to finish..but what i want is the progrss bar rotate till the activity is not finish...so why this happpen.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question...is there a way to restate it?

Comment: Actually i want to say that sometime the orientations of progress bar and dismiss of progress bar takes at same time but in some case the orientation stop, wait the progress dialog to dismiss and and then suddenly dismiss.